# Order by in nested eager loading in sequelize not working

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, eager-loading

i have four model Tehsil, Ilr, Patwar, and Villages.
and their association is

Tehsil -> 1:m -> Ilr -> 1:m -> Patwar -> 1:m -> Villages

i want to to apply order by on all four of my models.

Query:

```
var tehsilQuery = {
    include: [{
        model: Ilr,
        as: 'GirdawariKanoongo',
        include: [{
            model: Patwar,
            as: 'GirdawariPatwar',
            include: [{
                model: Villages,
                as: 'GirdawariVillages',
            }]
        }]
    }],
    order: [
        ['tehsil_name', 'ASC'],
        [ {model: Ilr, as: 'GirdawariKanoongo'}, 'kanoongo_name', 'ASC'],
        [ {model: Patwar, as: 'GirdawariPatwar'}, 'patwar_area', 'ASC'],
        [ {model: Villages, as: 'GirdawariVillages'}, 'village_name', 'ASC'],
    ]
};
return Tehsils.findAll(tehsilQuery);

[Error: 'girdawari_patwar' in order / group clause is not valid association]
```

order by is working if i remove `Patwar` and `Villages`(lat two model) from `order`.

Comment: The underscore in the association name in the error suggests Sequelize is trying to auto-generate the association name, though I'm not sure why. Can you post the code where you set up your associations?

Comment: @TomJardine-McNamara here look i solved it, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i solved it.
here's how `order` looks:

```
order: [
        'tehsil_name',
        'GirdawariKanoongo.kanoongo_name',
        'GirdawariKanoongo.GirdawariPatwar.patwar_area',
        'GirdawariKanoongo.GirdawariPatwar.GirdawariVillages.village_name' 
       ]
```

all i have to do is: using the `as` in association of table and chaining them followed by `column_name` on which `order` supposed to apply.

Answer (score 29):

Another working example with nested ordering:

```
order: [  
  [ { model: chapterModel, as: 'Chapters' }, 'createdAt', 'ASC'], 
  [ { model: chapterModel, as: 'Chapters' }, 
    { model: partModel, as: 'Parts' }, 'createdAt', 'ASC'] 
],
```

where part and chapter have M:1 relation.

Answer (score 4):

Our scenario was with two nested `include` statements where the inner most nesting was not ordering correctly. By applying the `ordering` at the highest level of the `findAll` we were able to successfully return the ordered object.

model relationship as follows for our `surveySet.findAll`:

- suveySet hasMany surveys
- surveys belongsToMany questions

  ```
  order: [  
      [ { model: survey, as: 'survey' }, 'subjectId', 'ASC'], 
      [ { model: survey, as: 'survey' }, 
        { model: question, as: 'question' }, 'id', 'ASC'] 
  ]
  ```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone wondering how it could be achieved using object style definition, this is how it would be solved.
You could find more information about ordering in [Sequelize documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#ordering-and-grouping).

```
order: [
    ['tehsil_name', 'ASC'],
    [ {model: Ilr, as: 'GirdawariKanoongo'}, 'kanoongo_name', 'ASC'],
    [ {model: Ilr, as: 'GirdawariKanoongo'}, {model: Patwar, as: 'GirdawariPatwar'}, 'patwar_area', 'ASC'],
    [ {model: Ilr, as: 'GirdawariKanoongo'}, {model: Patwar, as: 'GirdawariPatwar'}, {model: Villages, as: 'GirdawariVillages'}, 'village_name', 'ASC'],
]
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I think the documentation is not at all clear about this. With the same example you posted, how would you order the models by two or more columns?

Comment: Hi @F_Bass, this is a bit old in my memory but this example sorts by 4 columns already, if you need more you can just append new orders in the `order` array and fit the order statement as you need.