# How to get Sequelize results WHERE MAX timestamps_of_multiple_nested_objects are greater than a certain date?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have one main object that I need query results for, based on the timestamps of multiple HasMany note objects related to the main table. There are up to 3 different types of note objects that can be attached to one main object.

With Sequelize, I need to find the max timestamp for each note, then return a member if **all** of those timestamps are greater than x days old.

Both attempts below seem like they should work. This first tells me I'm using MAX wrong:

```
    main_object.findAll({
      include: [
        {
          model: this.database.note_type1,
          as: 'note_type1',
          required: false,
        },
        {
          model: this.database.note_type2,
          as: 'note_type2',
          required: false,
        },
      ],
      where: {
        [Sequelize.Op.or]: [
          Sequelize.where([Sequelize.fn('max', Sequelize.col('note_type1.updated_at')), 'max_updated_at']),
          {
            'max_updated_at': {
              [Sequelize.Op.lt]: max_date,
            },
          },
          Sequelize.where([Sequelize.fn('max', Sequelize.col('note_type2.updated_at')), 'max_updated_at']),
          {
            'max_updated_at': {
              [Sequelize.Op.lt]: max_date,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
   });
```

I've also tried ordering the includes by timestamp and limiting to 1, which says "column updated_at doesn't exist":

```
main_object.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: this.database.note_type1,
      as: 'note_type1',
      required: false,
      order: [
        ['updated_at', 'DESC'],
      ],
      limit: 1,
    },
    {
      model: this.database.note_type2,
      as: 'note_type2',
      required: false,
      order: [
        ['updated_at', 'DESC'],
      ],
      limit: 1,
    },
  ],
  where: {
      [Sequelize.Op.or]: [
        {
          '$note_type1.updated_at$': { [Sequelize.Op.lt]: max_date },
        },
        {
          '$note_type2.created_at$': { [Sequelize.Op.lt]: max_date },
        },
      ],
   },
)};
```

With this last solution, I understand Sequelize may not allow ordering this way - [however, the one solution I've found does not let me limit or max, it simply orders.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40202540/order-by-in-nested-eager-loading-in-sequelize-not-working)

Comment: we need provide two argments,so `Sequelize.fn('max', Sequelize.col('note_type1.updated_at'))` is wrong

Comment: please try with `updatedAt`

Comment: ‘updatedAt’ is not the problem, we’ve customized the timestamp column names in our database to be underscored. What do you mean by two arguments? Which method needs two, ‘fn’ or ‘max’?

Comment: Sequelize.fn('max', Sequelize.col('note_type1.updated_at'), OTHER_COLUMN)

Comment: yet, problem occur now ?